# Resolve path to current file

Tags: vimscript

I have an abbrevation for running `git blame` on the current file, but it fails in the presence of symlinks.

Here's the abbreviation

```
cnoreabbrev gbl ! ( cd %:h ; exec git blame %:t )
```

My `.vimrc` is a symlink to `~/config/vim/vimrc`.

```
$ ls -l .vimrc | cut -d' ' -f8-
16 Jan 29 20:54 .vimrc -> config/vim/vimrc
```

When I open my `.vimrc` from the home directory, it doesn't show me the git blame because I'm not inside the project root.

Is there something kind of like `realpath(3)` that I can use from the vim side to get a canonical path to the current file? I'd like to replace `%:h` with a canonical path to the directory containing the current file and `%:t` the corresponding file name.

Comment: Have you given thought to using [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)? Fugitive.vim provides the `:Gblame` command. Nice write up here: [Every line of code is always documented](http://mislav.net/2014/02/hidden-documentation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this abbreviation:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> gbl getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdpos() == 4 ? '! ( cd '.fnamemodify(resolve(expand('%')), ':h').' ; git blame '.fnamemodify(resolve(expand('%')), ':t').' )' : 'gbl'
```

---

It uses the `resolve()` function to resolve the symbolic links, and `fnamemodify()` to extract the head of the path as well as the filename component:

```
fnamemodify(resolve(expand('%')), ':h')    → head of the path
fnamemodify(resolve(expand('%')), ':t')    → tail of the path
```

Also, it makes sure that your abbreviation is only expanded on a regular Ex command line (`getcmdtype() == ':'`), and only if you're at the very beginning of the line (`getcmdpos() == 4`).

If you wanted the abbreviation to be expanded anywhere on the command line, you could remove the 2nd condition:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> gbl getcmdtype() == ':' ? '! ( cd '.fnamemodify(resolve(expand('%')), ':h').' ; git blame '.fnamemodify(resolve(expand('%')), ':t').' )' : 'gbl'
```

Comment: Why is the 4 in `getcmdpos(4)` ... uh ... 4? Is it 1 for the `:` and 3 for the `gbl`?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet  `4` stands for the position of the cursor on the command line. It's expressed as a byte count. When you type `gbl` at the beginning of the line, the next byte after the cursor is the 4th, because the weight of `gbl` in bytes is `3`. If you don't like this condition, you could replace it with `getcmdline() ==# 'gbl'`.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the `4`, I was just trying to figure out whether it was a magic constant that meant "the first command" or not. lt's neat and only somewhat terrifying that you can define a command/alias/abbrevation that can inspect its calling context like that.

Comment: Yes, as soon as you pass the argument `<expr>` to `:cnoreabbrev`, you can use the functions `getcmdline()`, `getcmdtype()`, `getcmdpos()` to check the contents of the command line, its type, and the position of the cursor. Then, depending on the result, you can expand your abbreviation differently.