# cnoreabbrev do not expand abbreviations in command history

Tags: command-line

Is it possible to configure vim to store commands in your command history without abbreviations expanded?

For instance I have the following command (to make it easy to switch back and forth between header and source files)

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> cv 'edit %:r.cpp'
```

However, if I type `:cv<cr>` and then type `up` I see

```
:edit %:r.cpp
```

in the command window rather than

```
:cv
```

Is there a way to configure the command history (either globally or on a per-abbreviation basis) to not be stored in expanded form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how reliable it is, but I came up with this:

```
fu! s:cnorea(lhs, rhs) abort
    let s:counter = get(s:, 'counter', 0) + 1
    fu! s:cnorea_{s:counter}() abort closure
        call timer_start(0, {
                          \  -> execute('if histget(":", -1) ==# '.string(a:rhs)
                          \ .'|              call histdel(":", -1)
                          \   |          endif
                          \   |          call histadd(":", '.string(a:lhs).')')
                          \ })
        return a:rhs
    endfu

    exe printf('cnorea <expr> %s
             \                   getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdpos() ==# %d
             \                   ?    <sid>cnorea_%d()
             \                   :    %s'
             \ , a:lhs, strlen(a:lhs)+1, s:counter, string(a:lhs))
endfu

call s:cnorea('cv', 'e %:r.cpp')
```

It seems to work as you want: it expands `cv` into `e %:r.cpp`, and logs `cv` in the command-line history. However, it relies on a timer, so if you want to test it, you first need to check that `:echo has('timers')` returns `1`.

You could define as many similar abbreviations as you want, by invoking `s:cnorea()`, passing to it the `{lhs}` and `{rhs}` of your abbreviations. Examples:

```
call s:cnorea('abcd', 'echo "hello"')
call s:cnorea('xyz', 'echo "world"')
```

---

It works like this:

```
call s:cnorea('cv', 'e %:r.cpp')
```

Invokes `s:cnorea()`, passing the strings `'cv'` and `'e %:r.cpp'` as arguments. The latter does 2 things:

1. define the function `s:cnorea_1()`
2. define the abbreviation:

   `cnorea <expr> cv getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdpos() ==# 3 ? <SID>cnorea_1('cv', 'e %:r.cpp') : 'cv'`

Like your original abbreviation, this one uses an expression as its `{rhs}`. The expression tests whether you're on a regular Ex command line (`getcmdtype() ==# ':'`), and whether you've typed `cv` at the beginning of the line.

If any of these 2 conditions isn't satisfied, the expression returns `cv`, which negates the expansion. Otherwise, it's expanded into the output of another function `s:cnorea_1()`, which is defined like this:

```
fu! s:cnorea_1() abort closure
    call timer_start(0, {
                      \  -> execute('if histget(":", -1) ==# '.string(a:rhs)
                      \ .'|              call histdel(":", -1)
                      \   |          endif
                      \   |          call histadd(":", '.string(a:lhs).')')
                      \ })
    return a:rhs
endfu
```

It returns your the expansion of your abbreviation, but before that, it calls a timer which in turn will call `histdel()` to delete `:e %:r.cpp` from the history, and `histadd()` to add `cv` in the history.

A timer allows you to defer the execution of a function or a funcref. From the perspective of the timer, the latter is called a callback. Here, the timer doesn't call a function, but a lambda expression, which is a special kind of funcref (see `:h Funcref`).

The syntax of a lambda expression is as follows:

```
{ args -> expr }
```

Example:

```
:echo { x,y -> x+y }(1,2)
   3
```

It returns `3`, because `3` is the image of `(1,2)` under the function `f: x,y -> x+y`.

The lambda expression used in the timer is:

```
  {
\  -> execute('if histget(":", -1) ==# '.string(a:rhs)
\ .'|              call histdel(":", -1)
\   |          endif
\   |          call histadd(":", '.string(a:lhs).')')
\ }
```

The purpose of this lambda expression/callback is to execute some Ex commands. But Ex commands are not expressions, so you can't write them directly. You have to wrap them inside the function `execute()`, which, as any function, is an expression. It takes as argument an Ex command (or a sequence of Ex commands separated by bars) and returns its output.

It doesn't need any argument, so there's nothing before the arrow `->`. It's just a routine which will execute:

```
if histget(":", -1) ==# 'e %:r.cpp'
    call histdel(":", -1)
endif
call histadd(":", 'cv')
```

This checks whether the last entry in the command-line history is `e %:r.cpp` (it should be, it's just a precaution), removes it if this is the case, then adds `cv`.

---

To summarize, when you execute `:cv` at the beginning of the command-line, it should be expanded into `:e %r.cpp`, but in the process, a timer is called to replace `:e %:r.cpp` with `:cv` in the history.

On my machine, although the callback is invoked after `0` ms, it's not instantaneous. Therefore, if you execute `:cv`, Vim should expand it into `:e %:r.cpp`, then replace it in the history. If on your machine, the callback is instantaneous, you should increase its waiting time, by replacing the 1st argument passed to `timer_start()` with another arbitrary value (as an example, with `1`, for `1`ms).

Also, it's not completely reliable, because if you expand your abbreviation, without executing it immediately:

```
:cv
    hit <space> to expand `cv`
:e %:r.cpp 
    during a few seconds, edit the command-line, maybe to add another command
    hit <Enter>
```

... then the timer will be called too soon, and in your history, you'll get both entries:

```
:cv
:e %:r.cpp
```

Again, you could increase the waiting time (`1000` ms, `5000` ms, ...), but it's a hack.

---

A few other notes to better explain the code.

The counter is needed to make the functions used by every abbreviation unique:

```
let s:counter = get(s:, 'counter', 0) + 1
```

It's evaluated inside the function name, through an element of syntax called `curly braces name` (see `:h curly-braces-names`):

```
fu! s:cnorea_{s:counter}() abort closure
"            └─────────┤
"                      └ curly braces names
```

This means that the 1st time you call `s:cnorea()`, it will define the function `s:cnorea_1()` for your 1st abbreviation. The 2nd time, it will define the function `s:cnorea_2()` for your 2nd abbreviation, and so on.

---

You don't need to pass the arguments from `s:cnorea()` to `s:cnorea_1()`, because of the `closure` attribute (see `:h closure`). Thanks to this, inside `s:cnorea_1()`, you can refer to variables which were defined in the scope of the outer function (`s:cnorea()`). So, even though `a:lhs` and `a:rhs` are in the scope of the arguments of `s:cnorea()`, `s:cnorea_1()` can still access them.

---

The abbreviation is installed by executing the output of a `printf()` invocation. You don't need it, you could install it without `printf()`:

But, `printf()` allows you to separate the code from the expressions it contains. Compare:

```
exe ' cnorea <expr> '.a:lhs
  \.'                       getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdpos() ==# '.(strlen(a:lhs)+1)
  \.'                       ?    <sid>cnorea_'.s:counter.'()'
  \.'                       :    '.string(a:lhs)
```

vs:

```
exe printf('cnorea <expr> %s
         \                   getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdpos() ==# %d
         \                   ?    <sid>cnorea_%d()
         \                   :    %s'
         \ , a:lhs, strlen(a:lhs)+1, s:counter, string(a:lhs))
```

You can use whichever version you find more readable (if any).

Comment: `strlen(a:lhs)+1` doesn't that break on multibyte characters?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Initially I thought that multibyte characters would break too, so I used `strchars()`. But I don't think so anymore, because `getcmdpos()` returns the position of the cursor in term of byte count, not in term of character count. However, you're right, there was a problem with multibyte characters, because I think they aren't allowed in a function name (at least I can't define a function whose name contains `à` - E124, E193). So, inside the inner function name, I replaced the `lhs` of the abbreviation with a simple counter.

Answer (score 1):

So, user-defined commands *must* begin with an uppercase letter. This namespacing rule prevents user-defined commands from trampling built-in vim functionality.

I think what I really wanted to do in the above example is define my own command that mimics the look and feel of a built-in command. (begins with a lowercase letter and appears literally in the command history).

One way to achieve this is to define a user-defined command that's uppercase (like `CV`) and have `cv` be an abbreviation for that. However, the body of the uppercase command checks if it's being called in command position and expands into the lowercase command (`cv`) if it isn't.

Here's an example showing how to do that for my `hj` and `cv` abbreviations (which just take you to a header or source file in the same directory)

```
command! HJ edit %:r.h
cnoreabbrev <expr> hj getcmdtype() !=# ':' ? 'hj' : 'HJ'
command! CV edit %:r.cpp
cnoreabbrev <expr> cv getcmdtype() !=# ':' ? 'cv' : 'CV'
```

In your history `:hj` will still show up as `:HJ` when you press up, but the effect isn't nearly as jarring as expanding into `:edit %:r.h`.

`getcmdtype` expands into a string indicating the context that the command is being invoked in.

More information on writing commands with "defensive" expansions is here:

[Resolve path to current file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11226/resolve-path-to-current-file/11227#11227)

using

```
command! CV edit %:r.cpp
cnoreabbrev <expr> cv CV
```

is tempting, but a really bad idea. If you type `/cv` to search for `"cv"`, then the abbreviation will get expanded and your search will become `/CV`. This is probably not what you wanted.

The linked answer also goes into some detail about detecting the "cursor position" when expanding command abbreviations, but I haven't found that necessary (yet).

EDIT:

The `getcmdpos() ==# 3` condition (or whatever 1 + the length of the abbreviation is) is actually very important.

`hj` and `cv` are uncommon enough that they don't often appear as "words" on their own. But if they ever do appear (say you make a `foo.hj`) file by mistake, then `foo.hj` will get expanded into `foo.HJ`.

The `getcmdtype() !=# ':'` check is not as strict as one might think.